# Flextable sizing with Quarto revealjs output

Tags: r, quarto, reveal.js, flextable

The table sizing functions don't seem to do much to change the dimensions of flextable objects for revealjs slide outputs for Quarto.  The default output has very small font, lots of padding, and rows that extend beyond the slide dimensions.  Am I missing something or is it just not compatible with revealjs output?  All I want is a table that's readable with minimal white space.

A MWE:

````
---
format: revealjs
---

```{r}
library(flextable)
flextable(head(cars))
```
````

Produces a slide like this:

[image]

Changing the standard sizing options does very little:

````
---
format: revealjs
---

```{r}
#| ft.top = 0
library(flextable)
library(dplyr)
flextable(head(cars)) %>% 
  padding(padding = 0, part = 'all') %>%
  line_spacing(space = 0, part = 'body') %>%
  line_spacing(space = 0, part = 'header') %>%
  height_all(height = 0) %>%
  hrule(rule = 'exact')
```
````

[image]

Comment: what version do you use? It is supposed to be compatible (it is at least on my computer).

Comment: Can confirm. It is working in latest R (4.3.1) and flextable (0.9.2) versions for me.  (The table is squished and unreadable because of 0 line spacing).

Comment: I was using R 4.2.3, I can confirm it works on R 4.3.1 and flextable 0.9.3.

Answer (score 0):

This works on R 4.3.1 and flextable 0.9.3, previously it was not working on R 4.2.3.